# EF Foreign Key using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here are my models. I have one to one mapping for Vehicle and Driver. I will have the vehicle created first and then map the driver to the vehicle.

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle  { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public int VehicleGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleGroup Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use VehicleId property in Driver class to keep id of vehicle the driver is driving.

I've written the following Fluent API code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.Driver)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

But it creates a new column in Drivers table - Vehicle_VehicleId and maps it to the VehicleId on Vehicle table. I want the VehicleId of Driver table to map.

Also, i'm brand new to EF and Fluent API. I find it extremely confusing choosing between WithRequiredDependent and WithRequiredPrincipal. Would be glad if you can describe it in simple words. Thanks.

Comment: You can think of dependents and principals as Entity Framework asking you: 'If you want to insert records of these tables, where should should I insert records first, table A or table B?' If you choose table A as the principal, table B will contain a foreign key to table A. The Fluent API has excellent c# documentation by the way, you should read the description on "WithRequiredDependent" and "WithRequiredPrincipal" carefully.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This line:

> public int VehicleId { get; set; }

is telling EF, [through code-conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj679962.aspx), that you want a foreign key in `Driver` pointing to `Vehicle`.

The following is telling EF that you want a 1:1 relationship from `Driver` to `Vehicle`:

> public virtual Vehicle Vehicle  { get; set; }

You should remove both and stick with your Fluent API configuration.

**Regarding [WithRequiredPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679449.aspx) vs. [WithRequiredDependent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg671273.aspx):**

You are specifying a compulsory relationship between `Vehicle` and `Driver`, with navigation from `Vehicle`to `Driver`, thus: Vehicle 1 --> 1 `Driver`

(Vehicle is the principal and `Driver` the dependent, since the navigation property is located in `Vehicle`and pointing to `Driver` .)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.Driver)
            .WithRequiredDependent();
```

You are specifying a compulsory relationship between `Vehicle` and `Driver`, with navigation from `Driver` to `Vehicle`, thus: `Vehicle` 1 <-- 1 `Driver`

(`Vehicle` is the dependent and `Driver` the principal, since the navigation property is located in `Driver` pointing to `Vehicle`.)

These two are analogous:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasRequired(v => v.Driver)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.Vehicle)
            .WithRequiredDependent();
```

Comment: @jnovo "You should remove both and stick with your Fluent API configuration."

if you do that, then how can you use "HasRequired(v => v.Vehicle)" with no reference to Vehicle?

Comment: @RobWashington in his Fluent API configuration he used the Driver property of Vehicle, not the other way around; the last line of code in my answer which you are referring to is just an example of an alternative, analogous configuration for the sake of completion

Answer (score 3):

EF creates the `Vehicle_VehicleId` column because you have `VehicleId` and `Vehicle` on your `Driver` Entity.

Remove `VehicleId` and `Vehicle` from your `Driver` Entity:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
        .HasRequired(d => d.Driver)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

you are setting the relationship so no need to include manual properties in your entity classes.

You get the `VehicleId` from the navigation property `Vehicle`:

```
IQueryable<int> vehicleIds = context.Drivers.Select(x => x.Id == 123).Vehicles.Id;
```

Comment: I've removed it, but it still creates Vehicle_VehicleId. Not the VehicleId in drivers table.

Comment: It's because you are using the fluent api to define relationships. I have updated my answer. Remove the virtual properties too.