# EF6 Code First, multiple cascade paths, and strange FK behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm going to try to put only the relevant parts of the model here, because there are quite a lot of classes. Hopefully it's enough to capture the problem:

```
public class Solve
{
    public int SolveID { get; set; }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public int BillID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }

    public int? PanelID { get; set; }
    public virtual Panel Panel { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [StringLength(48)]
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public State State { get; set; }

    public double Latitude  { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public double Capacity { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProfileSample> ProfileSamples { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileSample
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Profile")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public TimeSpan TimeOfDay { get; set; }

    public double SampleValue { get; set; }
}
```

So it was all working fine until I introduced the `Solve` class, at which point it started complaining about "multiple cascade paths". I added the following to the context and it seemed to be OK from then on:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Solve>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Location)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Except that it wasn't behaving properly:

```
using (Model.BlueData bd = new Model.BlueData())
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    s = new Model.Solve()
    {
        Location = bd.Locations.Find(rng.Next(0, bd.Locations.Count())),
        Bill     = bd.Bills.Find(rng.Next(0, bd.Bills.Count())),
        Profile  = bd.Profiles.Find(rng.Next(0, bd.Profiles.Count()))
    };

    bd.Solves.Add(s);
    bd.SaveChanges();

    s = bd.Solves
        .Where(u => u.SolveID == s.SolveID)
        .Include(u => u.Location)
        .Include(u => u.Profile)
        .Include(u => u.Profile.ProfileSamples)
        .Include(u => u.Bill)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So the above code just generates a random `Solve` object, adds it to the data context, and then retrieves it again along with all the associated data. There's certainly a more elegant way of doing this, but right now this is just testing code to make sure the other parts of my app are working.

So as expected, when I create the `Solve s` object, `s.Location` is a particular location, with ID, say, `1609`, and of course `s.LocationID` and `s.SolveID` both equal `0`.

Upon adding it to the data context and saving changes, the `s.SolveID` equals the location's ID (`1609`, in this example). It's very strange. I tried adding a `[Key]` attribute to `SolveID` and `[ForeignKey("Location")]` to `LocationID` in the `Solve` class, but it made no difference.

I've tried various things like removing `Profile` from `Solve`, or removing the `List<Profile> Profiles` from Location. I don't remember now exactly, but a few things did work to correct the `s.SolveID` set to the location's ID behaviour.

But these properties are all there for a reason, and if possible I'd prefer not to have to remove them just to get this working. I don't understand why this is happening, or how to correct it properly. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I think the Foreign key will need to be added back, ether as a data annotion (which you already tried- and i thought was the solution) or maybe adding it using the fluent api would work. this might fix it, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229373/ef-foreign-key-using-fluent-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `Location` is being referred in `Solve` object, so location is the principal and solve is dependent, I think in that case this mapping is wrong -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Solve>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Location)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

It should be -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Solve>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Location)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Secondly, since `Solve` referencing with the foreign key the definition should be -

```
public class Solve
{
    public int SolveID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Location")]
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Profile")]
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Bill")]
    public int BillID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Panel")]
    public int? PanelID { get; set; }
    public virtual Panel Panel { get; set; }
}
```

Thirdly, when saving objects, you have to save the 1) principal ones first, otherwise EF will try to create new entries or 2)you have to attach them manually. Among these the easiest that I found is (1), after saving the principal end I assign only the foreign key and EF works as expected.

```
using (Model.BlueData bd = new Model.BlueData())
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    s = new Model.Solve()
    {
        LocationID = bd.Locations.Find(rng.Next(0, bd.Locations.Count())).LocationID,
        BillID     = bd.Bills.Find(rng.Next(0, bd.Bills.Count())).BillID,
        ProfileID  = bd.Profiles.Find(rng.Next(0, bd.Profiles.Count())).ProfileID
    };
    s.Bill = s.Location = s.Profile = null; //otherwise EF tries to create them
    bd.Solves.Add(s);
    bd.SaveChanges();

    s = bd.Solves
        .Where(u => u.SolveID == s.SolveID)
        .Include(u => u.Location)
        .Include(u => u.Profile)
        .Include(u => u.Profile.ProfileSamples)
        .Include(u => u.Bill)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

EDIT 1:  The location class to be -

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]  //mark location ID as primary key
    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [StringLength(48)]
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public State State { get; set; }

    public double Latitude  { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This line: `s.Bill = s.Location = s.Profile = null;`, is it necessary? You said otherwise EF will try to create them, but they should already be `null`, right?

Comment: Yeah, but this just to make sure they are null. You are not going to have the same code everywhere. And if it solved your problem, please accept as answer, so others with same problem know this could be a solution.

Comment: I implemented the changes you recommended, and now I get the error: Solve_Location_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Solve_Location_Source' in relationship 'Solve_Location'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: Because Location does not have a Int Key.

Comment: I don't understand? Location has `int LocationID` and `Solve` has `Location Location` and `int LocationID` with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute. What else is missing?

Comment: check EDIT, locationID name is not standard for ID, so you have to mark it as Key explicitly.

Comment: I added `[Key]` and I'm getting the same error. Why is `LocationID` not standard for the PK? I thought {classname}ID was the standard PK for {classname}? So for class `Location`, `int LocationID` should be PK?

Comment: The best way is to verify in the database table. I think you need one [Key] for solve as well. `[Key]public int SolveID { get; set; }`

Comment: I couldn't fix this issue at all except by changing to `int? LocationID` which eliminates the issue. By the way, your Fluent code was wrong; `.WillCascadeOnDelete(bool)` is not available from `.HasRequired()`.