# How to add a reference to a user in my entity in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following classes (Simplified):

```
public class Company {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public List<Farm> Farms {get;set;}
    public List<User> Employees {get;set;}
}

public class Farm {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Company Owner {get;set;}
}

public class User {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Guid CompanyId {get;set;}
    public Company Company {get;set;}
}
```

This all works fine.
Now I want to add the `User` that created the `Farm` as follow:

```
public class Farm {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Company Owner {get;set;}
    public User CreatedBy {get;set;} // <= 
}
```

This gave me the following error (which is kind of obviouse I guess):

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Farms_dbo.Users_CreatedBy_Id' on table 'Farms' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

So I googled and found how to disable cascade deleting (which I hope means it won't delete my `User` once a `Farm` is being deleted). So I've added this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Farm>().HasRequired(f => f.CreatedBy).WithRequiredDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

After this I'm getting the Following error:

```
Entities in 'DbContext.Users' participate in the 'Farm_CreatedBy' relationship. 0 related 'Farm_CreatedBy_Source' were found. 1 'Farm_CreatedBy_Source' is expected.
```

I also noticed that not only the `Farms`-table has an `User_Id`-field but the `Users`-table now also has a `Farm_Id`-field.

Which is not what I expected/want. This looks like a 1-to-1 relation to me where every `Farm` has a `User`.

What must I do to configure this so:

1. My `Farm` has a reference to a `User` which will not be deleted on Cascade
2. My `User` doesn't contain a list with all the `Farms` he created (because I will probably want something for other entities to and I don't want to have lists for all those entities in my Model, unless that's the way to do it ofcourse :D)

*********** EDIT *************

I completely missed the `List<User>` on the `Farm` which was actually causing the 'weird' Foreign Key `Farm_Id` on the `User`.

Comment: Do you already have data in your database when you disable cascade on delete? It looks like `HasRequired` is failing because Farms do not have a User.

Comment: This happens when initiating the database from scratch. The database gets created, but the seed seems to fail eventhough I'm passing in a user. But don't you think the created fields (Farm_Id & User_Id) are strange?

Comment: Looking at this SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229373/ef-foreign-key-using-fluent-api) that explains why you are getting a 1 to 1 relationship. Would it work if you remove the `WithRequiredDependent`?

Comment: I've tried different approaches now and I still either the circular deletion or it keeps adding a foreign key in user called `Farm_Id`.

Comment: This https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx looks like something I would want, but when I try this (bottom of that page) my `User` still gets that darned `Farm_Id` field...

Comment: A User can (potentially) create more than one farm. It's a one-to-many relationship. `.HasRequired()...WithRequiredDependent()` is one-to-one.

Comment: @Gert Arnold yes, thank you. I understand now and I also know what I was doing wrong. I completely missed another relation between Farm and User that caused the 'weird' foreign key in User but was completely valid in the end.

Comment: I just created a blank project with your models and it worked as expected for me. What was the relation you missed? Glad its sorted.

Comment: I updated the question. The relation that was already there was a `List<User> Viewers` on Farm. This was a list of users that could read information of the Farm. It was not properly configured either because user did not contain a list of Farms.